# How can I place text next to an image with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to use flexbox for the first time to put text next to image. I have 4 divs inside `.flex-container`: 1.image 2.title 3.button 4.text. The problem is only with 4 - text.
Somehow it doesn't work perfectly as you can see on the screen because text is placed below the image.

[image: expected result jpg]

```css
.flex-container {
  padding-top: 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.details-section {
  margin-top: 60px
}

.details-title {
  padding-left: 400px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
}

.details-price-button {
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  float: right;
  font-weight: 500;
  height: 100px;
}

.details-img {
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.details-description {
  margin-left: 450px;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="details-section">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="details-img">
      </div>
      <div class="details-title"> {{ product.name }} </div>
      <div class="details-price-button">{{ product.price }} PLN
        <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Add to cart
            </button>
      </div>
      <div class="details-description">{{ product.details }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, if you want to learn flexbox [Interneting is Hard](https://www.internetingishard.com/html-and-css/flexbox/) is a nice site to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fourth DIV is placed below the image because they are in a common container and `flex-wrap` is active.

To have Div#4 directly under #2 and #3, put these three (i.e. 2, 3 and 4) into a separate wrapper `div` (inside your current flex-container) to which you apply `display: flex` and `flex-wrap: wrap`, and erase `flex-wrap: wrap` from the settings of the current `.flex-container`.