# Adding texts beside an image using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image]

I am having trouble figuring out how to adjust every `<p>` tag. It always goes beside the `the name should be here`. I want the should be below the name.

```
<div class="card" style="width: 25rem;">
    <div class="card-body bg-light">
        <h5 class="card-title text-center">The title should be here...</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="card-img-top d-flex align-items-top bg-light p-2">
        <div>
            <a class="fancybox" href="admin/files/Images/ProfilePicture.png">
            <img src="admin/files/Images/ProfilePicture.png" style="width: 100px; height: 100px">
            </a>
        </div>
        <p class="col p-2 m-0">The name should be here...</p>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: See here for an example using flexbox... use flexbox.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62413587/html-css-flexbox-text-next-to-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="card" style="width: 25rem;">
    <div class="card-body bg-light">
        <h5 class="card-title text-center">The title should be here...</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="card-img-top d-flex align-items-top bg-light p-2">
        <div>
            <a class="fancybox" href="admin/files/Images/ProfilePicture.png">
                <img src="admin/files/Images/ProfilePicture.png" style="width: 100px; height: 100px">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">The name should be here...</p>
            <p class="card-text">age</p>
            <p class="card-text">address</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below will also work

```
<div class="card" style="width: 25rem;">
    <div class="card-body bg-light">
        <h5 class="card-title text-center">The title should be here...</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="card-img-top d-flex align-items-top bg-light p-2">
        <div>
            <a class="fancybox" href="admin/files/Images/ProfilePicture.png">
                <img src="admin/files/Images/ProfilePicture.png" style="width: 100px; height: 100px">
            </a>
        </div>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr><td><p class="col p-2 m-0">The name should be here...</p></td></tr>
        <tr><td><p class="col p-2 m-0">Age</p></td></tr>
        <tr><td><p class="col p-2 m-0">Address</p></td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
```